# Como alterar o icone do documento do Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Quero alterar o icone do documento do excel, para ter outra cara e parecer um executável, ou algo assim, podem me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer alterar o ícone do Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Para alterar o ícone basta apenas criar um atalho (ex. área de trabalho), clicar em propriedades do arquivo (atalho) e clicar no botão `Alterar Ícone` e escolha o ícone desejado.

Outra opção seria criar um arquivo **executável** para abrir o arquivo já com as **macros habilitadas**:

1. Crie um arquivo com o seguinte código, alterando a linha onde indica em qual pasta local está o arquivo e salve no local desejado (ex. C:\tmp) com extensão **.cs**:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

       static class Program
   {
       // variáveis de instãncia
       static object oExcel = null;
       static object oBooks = null;
       static object oBook = null;
       static object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
       static System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
           string CaminhoDoArquivo = @"C:\Caminho\Para\Seu\Arquivo\Excel\ExcelComMacros.xlsm";

           if (ExcelEstaInstalado())
           {
               try
               {
                   if (System.IO.File.Exists(CaminhoDoArquivo))
                   {
                       AbrirArquivo(CaminhoDoArquivo);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show(string.Format("O arquivo {0} não foi encontrado", CaminhoDoArquivo));
                   }
               }
               catch (System.IO.IOException)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Erro de acesso ao arquivo. Verifique o arquivo de configuração ou as permissões de pasta");
               }
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível encontrar a instalação do Microsoft Excel no seu computador");
           }

           Application.Exit();
       }

       private static void AbrirArquivo(string caminhoDoArquivo)
       {
           object oFileName = caminhoDoArquivo;
           oExcel = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"));
           oExcel.GetType().InvokeMember("AutomationSecurity", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oExcel, new object[] { 1 }, ci);
           oExcel.GetType().InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oExcel, new object[] { true }, ci);
           oBooks = oExcel.GetType().InvokeMember("Workbooks", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oExcel, null, ci);
           oBook = oBooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oBooks, new object[] { oFileName, oMissing, false }, ci);
       }

       public static bool ExcelEstaInstalado()
       {
           Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");

           if (officeType == null)
           {
               return false;
           }
           else
           {
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Esse é um arquivo em linguagem **C**.

2. Abra um prompt (Tecla do Windows + R e digite CMD)
3. Acesse a pasta `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`:

   ```
   cd c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
   ```
4. Insira o seguinte código:

   ```
   csc.exe /target:winexe /out:"C:\Caminho\Do\Executavel\ArquivoExecutavel.exe" "C:\Caminho\Para\Arquivo\C\ScriptEmLinguagemC.cs"
   ```

Lembrando de alterar os caminhos para onde estão os seus arquivos.

Pronto! Você terá um executável para rodar sua planilha.